# MongoDB group by query with random fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have database of albums
each document look like that

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("576a569a32f844c021019533"),
    "genres" : [
        "Rock", 
        "Funk / Soul", 
        "Blues"
    ], 
    "artistJoins" : [
        {
            "artist_name" : "Citizen Cope"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "Bullet And A Target",
    "tracklist" : [
        {
            "duration" : "4:22", 
            "position" : "A",
            "title" : "Bullet And A Target"
        },
        {
            "duration" : "3:22", 
            "position" : "A",
            "title" : "Unfaithful"
        }
    ]
}
```

i am trying to get the tracklist item for each document 
so i finally will have a list of tracklist item and artist name (from the artistJoins[0].artist_name)
the db is really huge something like 1000000 documents

i did something that work and its pretty fast (maybe i am wrong)

this is what i tried

```
 db.collection('releases').aggregate( [
        { $sample: {size: 100}},
        { $unwind : {path:"$tracklist" ,preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false,includeArrayIndex: "songposition" } },
        { $match: { $or: [{ genres: 'Rock' }, { genres: 'Hip Hop' }] }},
        { $project: {"_id":0,"tracklist": 1,"songposition":1, "artistJoins":1}}
    ] ,  function(err, result) {
        callback(result);
    });
```

this example take me around 1400 ms (is it fast?)
and btw the genres can changed but there are at least 100 result for each genre so its not that there is not enough data in the db
the problem with that query is that sometimes he gives me less the 100 tracklist and sometimes more
what is the best solution to get random 100 tracklist items with the artist name
for example in this document i will get this list

(by the way this is what i get now but sometimes its less then 100 and sometimes is more)

```
[
    {
     "atrist_name" : "Citizen Cope",
     "tracklist" :{
             "duration" : "4:22", 
             "position" : "A",
             "title" : "Bullet And A Target"
         }
    },
    {
     "atrist_name" : "Citizen Cope",
     "tracklist" :{
             "duration" : "3:22", 
             "position" : "A",
             "title" : "Unfaithful"
         }
    }
]
```

and to do so for all the other document till i get list of 100

hope i can get a better solution and even faster or at least not slower 
hope i am clear enoughe if not just tell me and i will update